# TFS 2010 Build and ClickOnce signing

Tags: msbuild, certificate, signing

I am trying to get the signing working with TFS 2010. I already imported the .pfx File in the Personal Store for the Build Computer. I read somewhere i have to do this for the account the build service is running under. But i don't know how i can do this for "NetworkService", which is the account under which my build service is running.

The error message i am getting of MSBuild:

Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store.

I read somewhere i have to use the sn -i mycert.pfx VS_XXX but i have no idea where to get the VS_XXX from?

Comment: SACO, any luck on this?  I am running in to the same exact problem.

Comment: I will post my solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution for me seems to use another user account for this. In my case I needed a valid **domain** user. Because the user needs to have the correct rights for the team foundation server.
I logged in with this user on the build machine and added the certificate to my certificates (you should be able to do this by double clicking it).

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  I just need to figure out how to get that new user account the correct permissions in TFS.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For me it was enough to give this user the same permissions like other developers.